how to download node_js in linux from terminal
I want to download and install node js engin in my local machine from the ease of my terminal . I've got a linux os distro called ubuntu. I haven't try anything so far related to this but rather find stackoverflow to a great place to start. So I asked the stackoverflow AI(I don't know what it's called, I haven't tried it yet!), and it gave me this form to fill. So,  I guess I would get the answer of my question after fill this up, but if it redirects me to the human guys, guys you can help me too!!

Do some of your own research before asking questions. Installing node is a very common task, and it takes time for people to read and answer your question. Respect people's time and ask when you are stuck.

The best way to install node js is by version manager like nvm  or fnm.
link to GitHub with a installation guide in the readme
after that you can run nvm install --lts for the latest long term support or with any other version nvm install 18
with nvm use 18 you can then activate the version you like. This is especially handy if dealing with multiple projects using different versions
